# How to delete all the emails in Outlook in all folders before a certain date?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, powershell

I made a mistake importing some old emails into my Outlook, and now things are quite messed up. I want to delete all the emails I have in all Outlook folders before a certain date, let's say `DD/MM/YYYY`. I tried both the Windows Outlook and the web-app, though only a limited number of search results are selectable in each round, which given the number of emails I have mistakenly imported, is a painstaking process to be done manually.

I did some searches to see if I can automate the process using PowerShell. I tried [this page](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/delete-mails-based-on-a-date-range-for-a-specific/c9a9d2bf-6d0f-43f1-9eac-08c4ae0d04ff), for example, thought the `search-mailbox` [cmdlet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/search-mailbox?view=exchange-ps) doesn't to be available in my PowerShell environment. I also checked the documentation on [this page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/powershell-managing-an-outlook-mailbox-with-powershell) though it is more confusing than helpful.

**P.S.** It is worth noting that I have admin rights on this machine with Windows 10 21H1 OS, Outlook 365, and Powershell `5.1.*`.

Comment: If there are a small number of folders, open a folder, sort by date, highlight from start point to end and delete. Verify and empty deleted items.

Comment: Do you have on prem Exchange server access? Is this for an On-prem Exchange mailbox or Exchange Online\M365? I can help depending on your environment and your level of access, and the versions\platform of Exchange your mailboxes are running. Let me know.

Comment: Dear @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle can you be kind to help me know how I can check whether I have "on prem Exchange server access" and other questions you asked?

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle the `Connect-ExchangeOnline` cmdlet is not available 

Comment: I just added an answer with more detail how to install, connect, run script, etc. Let me know how it goes and use caution to not delete anything you don't intend to.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Connect-ExchangeOnline](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/connect-exchangeonline):

1. **Install Exchange Online Management:**

   ```
   Install-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
   ```
2. **Run [`Search-Mailbox`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/search-mailbox) for the dates of the emails you need to delete via:**

   ```
   ### Recieved:
   -SearchQuery {Received:"<start date>..<end date>"}

   ### Sent:
   -SearchQuery {Sent:"<start date>..<end date>"}
   ```

   **Caution:** *Run script `## 2.` section first to ensure you get proper results and see item counts*:

   - **PowerShell Exchange Online:**

     ```
     ## 1. -- Connect to Exchange Online
     $emailAddr = "YourEmailAddress@company.com";
     Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement;
     Try { Disconnect-ExchangeOnline; } Catch { $false };
     $ExoStatus = Try { Get-MailboxLocation $emailAddr; } Catch { $false; };
     If (!$ExoStatus){ Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName $emailAddr; };

     ## 2. -- This will give you an estimated count of items
     Search-Mailbox YourUsername -SearchQuery {Sent:"1/1/2000..12/31/2019"} -EstimateResultOnly;

     ## 3. -- This will actually delete the content for the date period specified
     Search-Mailbox YourUsername -SearchQuery {Sent:"1/1/2000..12/31/2019"} -DeleteContent;
     ```
   - **PowerShell Exchange On-Premise:**

     ```
     ### Run this to get a list of Exchange on-prem server names
     $e = (Get-ADDomain).DistinguishedName;
     $d = dsquery * "cn=Configuration,$e" -Filter "(objectCategory=msExchExchangeServer)";
     $d | % { $_.split(",")[0].Split("=")[1] };

     ## 1. -- Use this to connect to the Exchange on-prem server remotely
     $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://MyExchServerName.MyDomain.com/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos
     Import-PSSession $Session -AllowClobber;

     ## 2. -- This will give you an estimated count of items
     Search-Mailbox YourUsername -SearchQuery {Received:"1/1/2000..12/31/2019"} -EstimateResultOnly;

     ## 3. -- This will actually delete the content for the date period specified
     Search-Mailbox YourUsername -SearchQuery {Received:"1/1/2000..12/31/2019"} -DeleteContent;

     Remove-PSSession $Session;
     ```

Comment: Note the `Sent:` can also be `Received:` but in my testing the result count is always the same. This should take care of all email items regardless of folder within the mailbox though. The example provided will wipe email between 1/1/2000 through 12/31/2019. Adjust the dates accordingly for your needs.

Comment: @Foad .... Let me know if you have trouble connecting this way. If you determine you are on prem for your Exchange mailbox which you are deleting items, I have something to help make the connection to it too. The `Search-Mailbox` cmdlet works with Exchange 2010, 2013, 2016, 2019, and Exchange Online. Figuring out how to make the connection to the necessary Exchange server if it's on prem is just a trivial matter. I will update the answer to include this should you require it to get your problem resolved, just let me know.

Comment: thanks a lot. I had to run `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` first prior to importing the module.

Comment: Can you help me know where I can find my username? is it my email address?

Comment: Yes, it should be your email address that you sign onto Outlook with or if you sign onto your computer with or the one you give out to people, etc. tied to the mailbox. In Outlook, the From field when you go to send a new email will also tell you your email address. @Foad

Comment: @Foad If Outlook does not show the From field and your email address when you hit New to create a new message, once that new message opened, go to **Options** > and then click **From** to show your email address. Here's a screen shot of what that looks like Outlook M365 with the dark theme though in my case: https://i.imgur.com/eD0Pw55.png

Comment: from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65954084/4999991) it seems that I also need to install `Install-Module ExchangePowerShell`

Comment: @Foad I just updated my answer with a section named **"PowerShell On-Prem Exchange"** that should help you find and make a connect remotely to any Exchange on-prem servers in your domain. Once you connect to the Exchange On-Prem, the example commands are the same basically but be sure to refresh to see the latest. Let me know how it goes and what other type of trivial matters/logic I can help you iron out to get your problem resolved.

Comment: @Foad Also note that in the **"PowerShell On-Prem Exchange"** script in the `## 1.` section on the line starting with `$session` you will want to change `-ConnectionUri http://MyExchServerName.MyDomain.com/PowerShell/ ` to be the name of the Exchange  server from the list with your actual server name and domain name in that `http://` URL. I assume you already know this but change it to for example if you were acme.org with Exchange server AcmeExch01 to be `http://AcmeExch01.acme.org` in that part of the URL.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done [withn Outlook Client](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/2176-outlook-delete-emails-after-before-certain-time.html) or via PowerShell:

1. [Connect to Exchange Online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell):

   ```
   Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement

   Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName youremailaddress@domian.com
   ```
2. Search mails:

   ```
   New-ComplianceSearch -Name "Delete Message" -ExchangeLocation youremail@domian.com -ContentMatchQuery '(Received:05/01/2022 00:00..05/01/2022 23:59)

   Start-ComplianceSearch -Identity "Delete Message"

   New-ComplianceSearchAction -SearchName "Delete Message" -Purge -PurgeType SoftDelete -force
   ```

Comment: Please use correct markdown for monospaced code and code boxes

Comment: @JW0914 What to read about the format you used in particular? The markdown that uses the 4 backticks for example, is this part of the built in format per the SU posts that go over this because the tool SU provides to write a post does not give those sort of options unless I'm overlooking something. What should I read as a starting point to make that as easy as writing the answer? Do you know this per front end web coding HTML, etc. or did you read about these formatting options in a howto post? I like simple when it come to writing a post though so the simpler the better for me personally.

Comment: @JW0914 And yes, if I'm overlooking something simple that is built in, I wouldn't be surprised either. Different web UI features and navigation gives me trouble sometimes not spotting something obvious. Happy to learn either way though. Thank you!

Comment: Formatting options can be found in the formatting bar on questions/answers, directly above the content box, with the formatting bar's question icon expanding a help section. There is no markdown that uses four backticks - single backticks are used for monospaced code, whereas three backticks are for code boxes. Monospaced code markdown is important for a few reasons, as web translators don't translate it _(a necessity)_ and its easier to notice and read, keeping commands on the same line & not line breaking them, which is imperative for clear understanding of where the command begins and ends

Comment: @JW0914 When I write an answer or a post, I typically use the options that are here: https://i.imgur.com/yEY1Vo5.png and I have not clicked the `(?)` there and then look over advanced help. While that detail is useful, I do not think the actual options from the bar provide all those level of formatting. For example the 3 backticks is not what you get when you click it to put the code block. You have to explicitly type the 3 backticks before and after you code block for that format and know that's what you are supposed to do.  I'll play with it more when I get some time though.

Comment: Screenshot linked to is the formatting bar. While the formatting bar's code link indents at four whitespaces on a new line, the help section shows three backticks under `Code`)_, I'm unsure why the formatting bar's code button is still using the antiquated four whitespaces _(results in significantly more storage overhead for content when scaled to an answer site like StackExchange)_; either/or can be used, however backticks allow specifying the specific syntax directlyafter them _(e.g. three backticks then bash, ini, xml, etc.)_, versus the inefficient way it must be done with four whitespaces